IntelliJ IDEA getter template Optional return value not output
I'm trying to create a code template which is a modified default template for a getter, which would return Optional of the member. The code I have is shown below:
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
java.util.Optional<$field.type> ##
#if($field.recordComponent)
${field.name}##
#else
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  is##
#else
  get##
#end
${name}##
#end
() {
  return Optional.ofNullable($field.name);
}

However when using this, the Optional<> is not output and just the field type:
public MyObject getMyObject()
{
    return Optional.ofNullable(myObject);
}

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Make sure that java.util.Optional is imported in your generated code or the fully qualified name (java.util.Optional) is used. You are already using java.util.Optional<$field.type> in the template, but if $field.type resolves to something unexpected, Optional<> might not appear as intended.

Bean properties should never use Optional for their type.  See Uses for Optional.
